# Using LDAP for authenticating users. Grails and Groovy

Tags: grails, ldap

I'm trying to use LDAP as a form of authentication for users in my system. Right now I have a login page that after they input their username and password. The system will check the username with the database and then checks their name to match it with the active directory so as to check whether the password matches. However, I'm not sure how to start implementing. So, is there anyone out there that can guide me with links and guides to have a kick start and how to complete this particular function.

Thank you guys so much :)

Answer (score 1):

look at the [spring-security-ldap plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ldap)

Comment: If you are using shiro, you can have a ldap realm